# Name space my backbone models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I currently set out my models like this:

```
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        photo: "img/placeholder.png",
        name: "",
        address: "",
        tel: "",
        email: "",
        type: ""
    }
});
```

and my collection like so:

```
var Directory = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact
});
```

Then in my main app.js file, I'm doing this to define my routes:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render().el);
    },

    routes: {
        "filter/:type": "urlFilter"
    },

    urlFilter: function (type) {
        directory.filterType = type;
        directory.trigger("change:filterType");
    },

});
```

I'm getting an error with the code below which tells me 'directory' is undefined.

```
    directory.filterType = type;
    directory.trigger("change:filterType");
```

In my view I new up the collection like so, `this.collection = new Directory(contacts);`

I'm pretty new to backbone and I'm not sure if Im doing things in the correct order, and that my collection doesn't exist at the time when I'm trying to do my filterType and Trigger or wether I have things completely wrong.

My code can be viewed here, http://dan.ms/backbone

Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

The `directory` variable seems to be created in a callback to `tpl.loadTemplates`. The variable is not available in the scope where it's being accessed inside your router. One way to do it would be to pass `directory` to the `AppRouter` constructor as a parameter. In `AppRouter`'s constructor, save it as a property, and access it in the `urlFilter` method via the current instance.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.directory = options.directory;
  },

  urlFilter: function (type) {
    this.directory.set("filterType", type);
  }
});

// Initialize with:
var directory = new DirectoryView;
var app = new AppRouter({ directory: directory });
Backbone.history.start();
```